# Invalid block tag 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, jinja2

I work on Django 1.11 and in my template file I've got this code :

```
{% for article in all_articles %}
    {% set color_category = 'light-blue' %}
    {% if article.category == 'SEO' %}
        {% color_category = 'light-blue' %}
    {% elif article.category == 'SEA' %}
        {% color_category = 'amber' %}
    {% elif article.category == 'Python' %}
        {% color_category = 'green' %}
    {% elif article.category == 'Django' %}
        {% color_category = 'light-green' %}
    {% else %}
        {% color_category = 'light-blue' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And Django returned me this error :

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 12: 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Have you got an idea ?
Ask if you need more info (like my settings file).

Thanks !

Comment: What are you trying to do? Django templates do not have a `set` tag and do not support assignment.

Comment: In Flask I could do set in Jinja2, but I didn't know that Django don't support it. I just want to declare a variable in my view to add a color on a specific label without doing a multiple If/html code.

Comment: I didn't know about FLask but i know django  So you can make templatetags for this and load that templatetags file in top of template page? Can you share code related of {% get %}?

Comment: I load nothing from my controller function. I create this variable directly in view :/

Comment: I think I will load this variable from my controller instead. But I think I'm not the only one who pass from Flask to Django and have the same issue :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`set` is not a valid tag in django. You should use `with` if you want to define a variable in your template.

```
{% with color_category='light-blue' %}     
    Do stuff
{% endwith %}
```

However, it's always better to do this kind of operation in the view in python.

Answer (score 4):

The solution above is correct, but with a minor mistake. There shouldn't be a space between the variable and its value, so the correct sintaxis should be:

```
{% with color_category='light-blue' %}     
    Do stuff
{% endwith %}
```